# Unity Resources folder not included in desktop build

Tags: unity-game-engine, resources

There seems to be some file size limit on the Resources folder before it stops being included in the build. We built for both Windows and Mac and neither include the files in the Resources folder. I'm trying to narrow it down to the exact file size where it stops working, but I'm currently around 160MB with it not working, and it works fine at around 80MB.

We've tried the following:

```
Resources.Load(filepath);
Resources.Load<GameObject>(filepath);
Resources.Load(filepath) as GameObject;
```

The files are txt files, 3DS files, and png files.

Our Resources folder is in the root of the Assets folder, so it should be included in the build.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I've asked on Unity's forum here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/resources-folder-not-included-in-desktop-build.350468/

Comment: I don't think there is a specific file size limit for files in the Resources folder. Particularly not at the sizes you mention. I would rather look into the specific file causing a problem perhaps? Do you get any errors during the build? Anything in  any of the logs? Could you try it with another resource of a similar large size, just to see if the specific file causes a problem and not the size itself.

Comment: Looks like this has been asked many times over the year on the Unity Answers site with no responses. On the Unity forum, however, you may be able to get a response from someone who works there.

Comment: "I'm currently around 160MB with it not working, and it works fine at around 80MB." I wonder if you were trying to load different files with a folder being 160MB and 80MB?

Comment: I've tried adding enough 3DS files to get it to 160MB and it also doesn't work, which leads me to believe it's not a specific file that's buggering it up.  I've also asked on the Unity forum, so hopefully something comes from that.

Comment: Why did you put txt, 3ds and png files in the Resources folder? txt and png files in the Resources folder can not be loaded as GameObject, though you may load text file as TextAsset and png as Texture.

Comment: I use StreamingAssets rather than Resources whenever I can.